# SQL Aliases ',' and + function

Tags: sql

What is the function of ',' and + on the given following SQL script?

```
SELECT CustomerName, Address+', '+City+', '+PostalCode+', '+Country AS Address 
FROM Customers;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `+` is only valid for numbers in SQL. Btw: w3fools is not a "good" learning resource. It's full of errors. The above statement is not valid (standard) SQL.

Comment: Thank you for that, I think it's mySQL, but not sure. Do you have any recommendations for learning resource?

Answer (score 0):

' is the delimiter for a string literal. ', ' is a string containing a comma and a blank.

So obviously this query selects CustomerName plus a concatenation of address and a comma and a blank and city and a comma and a blank and country, calling this new string Address.

The DBMS in question accepts a + for string concatenation. Either additionally to or instead of the standard operator || .

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you two columns: `CustomerName` and `Address`.
The `Address` will be composed of: `Address`, `City`, `PostalCode` and `Country` seperated by comma (`,`)

The `+` sign is used for concatenating strings in this specific SQL query.
Some DBMS like (MySql and Sybase) use the `+` for concatenation of strings.